# How do get the stream urls from kinox.to?

Tags: bash

I found the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get stream URLs for the second episode of the seventh season of futurama:
# kinox.sh futurama 7 2
# for shows with spaces, insert a plus sign instead:
# kinox.sh it+crowd 3 1

# grab the stream by searching for the show on kinox.to, filtering to only     show english versions, and extracting the internal show name
export stream_page=$(curl -sL "http://kinox.to/Search.html?q=$1" | pcregrep -M 'lng\/2\.png(\n|.)+?class="Title"' | pcregrep -o1 'Stream\/(.+?)\.html' | head -n 1)

# get the show's page, with the undocumented additional parameters for season and episode, and grab the "rel" attribute of the hoster list
export stream_rel=$(curl -sL http://kinox.to/Stream/$stream_page.html,s$2e$3 |grep rel= | pcregrep -o1 '<li i.+?rel="(.+?)"' | perl -pe 's/&amp;/&/g')

# for every rel attribute (which will contain season, episode, hoster id and mirror id)
while read -r line; do
# call the "secret" API. This will yield a JSON object, but since we're only interested in one attribute, we'll throw some regex on top and print the list of stream urls
curl -sL "http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/$line" | pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"' | tr -d '\' |perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
done <<< "$stream_rel"
```

How does it work or is there an easier way? I would like to transfer it to python. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your script. Have you debugged the variables to insure the `curl` and `read -r` commands are succeeding? (note not all versions of `read` support the `-r` option). Try running your script with, e.g. `sh -x yourscriptname.sh futurama 7 2` (or whatever show you are attempting to use instead of *futurama second episode season 7*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom line is you need to do basic debugging to find out where the problem lies in the script.

As mentioned in the comment, nothing obviously wrong stands out. (OK, I lied, there is an *obvious* problem, but given the way many modern shells interpret POSIX shell, it probably is handled without issue.) For the record, you are calling the POSIX shell `#!/bin/bash` as the shell interpreter, but you are feeding your `while` loop with a `herestring` which does not exist in POSIX shell.

How do you do general debugging? For starters, run your script with `sh -x scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3`, e.g.:

```
$ sh -x curl_stream_ex.sh futurama 7 2
++ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/Search.html?q=futurama'
++ pcregrep -M 'lng\/2\.png(\n|.)+?class="Title"'
curl_stream_ex.sh: line 8: pcregrep: command not found
```

On my box `pcregrep` wasn't installed, "is it installed on yours?" Fixing that, e.g.

```
$ sudo zypper in -r oss pcre-tools pcre-doc
<snip>
(1/2) Installing: pcre-doc-8.33-2.1.2 ......................[done]
(2/2) Installing: pcre-tools-8.33-2.1.2 ....................[done]
committingCommitResult  (total 2, done 2, error 0, skipped 0, updateMessages 0)
```

Try again (using `bash` as the interpreter this time, and using the provided example of `futurama 7 2`):

```
$ bash -x curl_stream_ex.sh futurama 7 2
++ pcregrep -o1 'Stream\/(.+?)\.html'
++ pcregrep -M 'lng\/2\.png(\n|.)+?class="Title"'
++ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/Search.html?q=futurama'
++ head -n 1
+ export stream_page=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder
+ stream_page=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder
++ curl -sL http://kinox.to/Stream/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder.html,s7e2
++ grep rel=
++ perl -pe 's/&amp;/&/g'
++ pcregrep -o1 '<li i.+?rel="(.+?)"'
+ export 'stream_rel=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=62&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=30&Mirror=1
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=33'
+ stream_rel='Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=62&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=30&Mirror=1
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=33'
+ read -r line
+ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2'
+ pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'
+ perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
+ tr -d '\'
tr: warning: an unescaped backslash at end of string is not portable
<snip>
```

OK, there is a warning, that isn't fatal, but let's go ahead and fix that. The good news is we now know the server is active, and there is something responding to the example `futurama 7 2`. To fix the `tr` non-portable unescaped backslash, the command:

```
tr -d '\'
```

(for portability) should be:

```
tr -d '\\'
```

Try again.

```
$ bash -x curl_stream_ex.sh futurama 7 2
++ pcregrep -M 'lng\/2\.png(\n|.)+?class="Title"'
++ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/Search.html?q=futurama'
++ head -n 1
++ pcregrep -o1 'Stream\/(.+?)\.html'
+ export stream_page=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder
+ stream_page=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder
++ curl -sL http://kinox.to/Stream/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder.html,s7e2
++ perl -pe 's/&amp;/&/g'
++ grep rel=
++ pcregrep -o1 '<li i.+?rel="(.+?)"'
+ export 'stream_rel=Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=62&Mirror=1
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=30&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=33'
+ stream_rel='Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=62&Mirror=1
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=30&Mirror=2
Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=33'
+ read -r line
+ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2'
+ pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'
+ tr -d '\\'
+ perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
+ read -r line
+ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=62&Mirror=1'
+ pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'
+ tr -d '\\'
+ perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
+ read -r line
+ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=30&Mirror=2'
+ tr -d '\\'
+ pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'
+ perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
+ read -r line
+ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=33'
+ pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'
+ perl -pe 's/\/Out\/\?s=//g'
+ tr -d '\\'
+ read -r line
```

No errors, but it looks like the `pcregrep` line of `pcregrep -o1 'map> <a href=\\"(.+?)\\"'` is returning nothing. Up to that point in the script, things look OK. Specifically, up though the `read -r` and the `curl` command on `$line`, the `curl` returns the following:

```
$ curl -sL 'http://kinox.to/aGET/Mirror/Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&Hoster=52&Mirror=2'
{"Stream":"<a href=\"http:\/\/shared.sx\/992ba73be8\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"\/gr\/sys\/player\/default.flash.png\" usemap=\"#Link\" width=\"752\" height=\"370\" border=\"52\" \/><\/a><map name=\"Link\"><area shape=\"rect\" coords=\"220,250,515,310\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"\" alt=\"Download This Movie\" title=\"Download This Movie\"><\/map>","Replacement":"<li id=\"Hoster_52\" class=\"MirBtn MirBtnA MirBaseStyleflv MirStyle52\" rel=\"Futurama_Into_the_Wild_Green_Yonder&amp;Hoster=52&amp;Mirror=3\">\t<div class=\"Named\">Shared.sx<\/div>\t<div class=\"Data\"><b>Mirror<\/b>: 3\/3<br \/><b>Vom<\/b>: 25.10.2015<\/div><\/li>","HosterName":"Shared.sx","HosterHome":"http:\/\/shared.sx"}
```

So, without knowing more, it appears that the stream format (or contents) for `http://kinox.to` has changed or been updated since whenever the script you *found* was written and today. What you will need to do, and what I cannot help you with as I have no idea what you are doing with the information, is to rewrite the *regex* used by `pcregrep` on the text returned by `curl` to parse it down to the url that contains the link to what you are attempting to get.

That's pretty much how you would approach solving the issue. It makes no difference whether you use `sh`, `bash` or `python`, without the correct `regex` none of the interpreters will return anything useful.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I followed your instructions and it finally works

Comment: Glad I could help Benni. If the answer was useful, and the problem is resolved, you can place a checkmark at the top left of the answer to let StackOverflow know that your issue has been resolved. Otherwise it will remain an unanswered question. Good luck with your streaming.